# LVM with same mount points

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, lvm, mount

I have a volume group called 'encrypted' and its device name is `/dev/xvdj`.

```
[root@s-mysql /]# lsblk
xvdj                     202:144  0   3T  0 disk
└─xvdj1                  202:145  0   3T  0 part
  ├─encrypted-home_vol  253:6    0   2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─encrypted-local_vol 253:7    0   2G  0 lvm  /usr/local
  ├─encrypted-opt_vol   253:8    0   4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─encrypted-tmp_vol   253:9    0   4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─encrypted-var_vol   253:10   0   3T  0 lvm  /var
```

I have another disk. This disk is also LVM and its group name is also called `encrypted` due to the way the disk was created. I want to do the following:

> create a symlink from new_disk (/var/lib/mysql) to old_disk (/var/lib/mysql)

So I did the following.

```
# rename the old encrypted to old
vgrename encrypted old

# update cahce
pvscan --cache
```

At this point I have

```
[root@s-mysql /]# lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
xvdf                     202:80   0   3T  0 disk
└─xvdf1                  202:81   0   3T  0 part
xvdj                     202:144  0   3T  0 disk
└─xvdj1                  202:145  0   3T  0 part
  ├─old-home_vol  253:6    0   2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─old-local_vol 253:7    0   2G  0 lvm  /usr/local
  ├─old-opt_vol   253:8    0   4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─old-tmp_vol   253:9    0   4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─old-var_vol   253:10   0   3T  0 lvm  /var
```

Notice `/dev/xvdf` is still not mounted yet. I hope so far make sense.

```
[root@s-mysql /]# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdf1
  VG Name               encrypted
  PV Size               <3.00 TiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              786431
  Free PE               13056
  Allocated PE          773375
  PV UUID               TSeqC4-EsEA-NBYf-3ACd-aNh7-9q7o-Op5yJU

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdj1
  VG Name               old
  PV Size               <3.00 TiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              786431
  Free PE               15359
  Allocated PE          771072
  PV UUID               usM0iR-1eGw-CeC8-BQd3-Hr9I-BezY-PRyp1K
```

Now, if I mount, I get this:

```
[root@s-mysql /]# vgchange -a y
  6 logical volume(s) in volume group "encrypted" now active
  5 logical volume(s) in volume group "old" now active
[root@s-mysql /]# lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda                    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1                 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdb                    202:16   0  25G  0 disk
└─xvdb1                 202:17   0  25G  0 part
xvdf                    202:80   0   3T  0 disk
└─xvdf1                 202:81   0   3T  0 part
  ├─encrypted-home_vol  253:0    0   2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─encrypted-local_vol 253:1    0   2G  0 lvm  /usr/local
  ├─encrypted-opt_vol   253:2    0   4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─encrypted-tmp_vol   253:3    0   4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  ├─encrypted-var_vol   253:4    0   3T  0 lvm  /var
  └─encrypted-usr_vol   253:5    0   9G  0 lvm
xvdj                    202:144  0   3T  0 disk
└─xvdj1                 202:145  0   3T  0 part
  ├─old-home_vol        253:6    0   2G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─old-local_vol       253:7    0   2G  0 lvm  /usr/local
  ├─old-opt_vol         253:8    0   4G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─old-tmp_vol         253:9    0   4G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─old-var_vol         253:10   0   3T  0 lvm  /var
```

This is not good. We have `/var`. My question is how do I just mount "`/var/lib/mysql`" from the new disk `/dev/xvdf` and create a symlink so I can replace the old `/var/lib/mysql` now given they both present `/var`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different mountpoint (for example `/var2`), mount there the desired LV, remove current `/var/lib/mysql` and create the softlink

```
ln -s /var2/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```